# iOS Getting ActionSheet-Like buttons

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uiactionsheet

I have an iOS iPhone app for which I need the Action Sheet-style buttons outside of an action sheet. I am talking about these buttons:

[image]

I've seen the eBay iPhone app do that and then have that button tinted blue, but I just can not figure out how to do it. I've been pondering and googling for this for quite a few days now. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used pre-built photoshop PSDs in the past to achieve this effect. My favorite so far is http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/2010/06/14/iphone-gui-psd-v4/

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking I'd have to go the route of PSDs and including images as well. I'll see how it works for me.

Comment: Also, I was wondering, how was the 'pressed' effect when you used those pre-made PSDs? Any examples you have I could take a look at?

Comment: @Tristan Seifert you can assign individual images to the button "states" ... normal, pressed, etc

Comment: I apparently overlooked the basics about buttons in IB there. I just sorta darkened my button, and I hope that's what I am supposed to do. It looks good! Thanks for that PSD though.

Comment: http://www.teehanlax.com/downloads/iphone-4-guid-psd-retina-display/ for the retina version

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your own view that mimics Apple's action sheet.  Here's a really nice post that has helped me to create something similar: 
 http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/andrew_homeyer/display_a_custom_uiview_like_a.html

Comment: I wanted to re-create the buttons on the action sheet, not the entire sheet itself, but this will prove useful eventually. Thanks for the link though!

Comment: @Tristan I should have read your question more clearly.  I now see that you just wanted the resources. Sorry about that. :)

Comment: Heh, I was gonna implement something like a custom action sheet anyways, so that came in handy ;)

Comment: Any other links on this, it seems a 404 now

Comment: I think the sample code from the post is here on GitHub: https://github.com/homeyer/CustomUIActionSheet . To be honest, though, this might serve you better: https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets

Answer (score 1):

To make the actionSheet black / transparent:

```
[actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
```